# How to make Telerik Editor Control Readonly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

I have implemented a Telerik Editor COntrol In my Web Page . Can Anyone tell me How to make it Readonly. I just want to prevent user to enter anything in Editor.

### Code Below--

```
 @{ Html.Telerik().Editor()
       .Name("Content")
       .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:150px;"})
       .Encode(true)
       .Tools(tools => tools
           .Clear()
           .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough().Subscript().Superscript().Separator()
           .FontName().FontSize()
           .FontColor().BackColor().Separator()
           .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull().Separator()
           .InsertUnorderedList().InsertOrderedList().Separator()
           .Indent().Outdent().Separator()
           .Break()).Render();  
                            }
```

Please Help me ASAP..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible currently.  What you have to do is render the text inside an `IFRAME` or `DIV` as a typical HTML element, then style the element to be similar to your Editors (height, border, background, etc).  It will appear to the user to be "disabled."

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Rich Text Editor through javaScript.Check below code.

```
  var editorInfo = $("#Content").data("tEditor");
        editorInfo.body.disabled = true;
```